# How to make iterm2 send Control-H for backspace so it works for all Linux shells

Tags: macos, vim, ssh, iterm

I had some problems with Terminal.app in OSX when my backspace key didn't have backspace behaviour.  Basically, pressing backspace caused a delete instead.  In Terminal you can fix this by going to Preferences/Settings/Advanced and ticking 'Delete sends Control-H' which works on all the servers that I SSH into.

I have now shifted to iTerm2 How do I do the same thing on iTerm2?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ok, fixed already sorry!  For anyone else who needs this:

```
iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Keys -> Key Mappings -> click on the + symbol  
-> Click to Set -> press backspace -> select 'Send ^H Backspace'
```

Comment: In newer versions, there's a checkbox for this.

Comment: It's now iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Keys ->  Key Mappings -> click on the + symbol -> Click to Set -> press backspace  -> select 'Send ^H Backspace'